# textConnection equivalent that can readBin

Tags: r, file-io, binaryfiles

I'm writing tests for a binary format parser, whose API accepts a Connection object. I'd like to put examples of binary data directly into test cases, as these examples are short and numerous.

If it was a text format, I'd just write:

```
test_that("readFoo parses message X", {
    data <- readFoo(textConnection("Bar"))
    expect_that(data$q, 1)
})
```

…but `readFoo` uses `readBin(…, 'raw')` internally, and this requires a binary connection, which textConnection is not. Therefore,

```
test_that("readFoo parses message X", {
    data <- readFoo(textConnection('\x01\x7a\x02\x2c\x7d\x0d\x5a\x0b\x0c\x01'))
    expect_that(data$q, 1)
})
```

fails with:

```
Error in readBin(conn, "raw", 10) : can only read from a binary connection
```

Is it possible to make this work?

Comment: @Thomas: I have no idea how did I miss this in the documentation. Could you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use [a "raw connection"](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rawConnection.html) via the `rawConnection()` function, which behaves basically like `textConnection()`. The cross-references in the base package documentation aren't great, so it can be easy to miss this one.